# Error copying cookies between webdriver and requests

Tags: python, cookies, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I am trying to copy cookies from a webdriver object to requests, as can be seen in the code below. I get this error message in the **last** statement of the script.

> TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

```
import requests
import cookielib
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://www.google.com/")

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()

#iterate the drive Cookies
for c in driver.get_cookies():
    print "%s -> %s" % (c['name'], c['value'])
    ck = cookielib.Cookie(name=c['name'], value=urllib.unquote(c['value']), domain=c['domain'], \
             path=c['path'], \
             secure=c['secure'], rest={'HttpOnly': c['http_only']}, \
             version =0,    port=None,port_specified=False, \
             domain_specified=False,domain_initial_dot=False, \
             path_specified=True,   expires=None,   discard=True, \
             comment=None, comment_url=None, rfc2109=False)
    print ck
    cj.set_cookie(ck)

rsp = requests.get('http://www.cisco.com/', cookies=cj)
```

Why do I get this error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

What version of requests are you using? There have been [significant changes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests#history) to the way requests handles cookies in the last few releases.

For me, your code runs without generating an exception using requests 0.14.0 (the most recent release at the time of writing).

Comment: Indeed, the new requests version (0.14) solves the problem. Many thanks.